# TCP and retransmission

Tags: tcp

I'm trying to understand how the transmission and ACK work in TCP. In this Figuure, when A retransmitt the seq 100 after he recive three duplikated ACK , B will answer with 121 ACK or 158 ACK ? 
[image]

Comment: Depends on B's reordering buffer size and the current window size.

Comment: Reciever re-AKCs last correctly recieved segment, it don't depand on buffers and windows size ..

Comment: @BatchyX the reordering buffer size should not be smaller than the window size, if there is actually such a thing as a separate reordering buffer.

Comment: You should be aware that any decent stack would support selective acknowledgements as defined in [RFC 2018](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2018.txt) and [RFC 2883](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2883.txt), so your question is largely hypothetical in nature.

Comment: @syneticon-dj SACK shouldn't influence the behavior of the ACK sequence number. It's an addition, not a replacement.

Comment: @KillianDS it is an addition, but it significantly changes the retransmission logic, thus theorizing about the vanilla ACK behavior and the resulting retransmission characteristics is just something for a "History of TCP" book or for people debugging particularly ancient or broken stacks.

Comment: @syneticon-dj even with SACK, the actual ACK that is being sent after the reception of the lost segment will not change. SACK will only improve that you won't retransmit the non-lost packets (which the question did not ask anything about)

Answer (score 1):

The retransmission topic has been widely documented all across the net and the relevant literature, so for the case of a retransmission due to segment timeout expiration I am just going to quote off ***[a Novell document with some packet capture examples](http://support.novell.com/techcenter/articles/ana20021203.html)***:

---

TCP implements reliability by sending an acknowledgment for data segments received. [...] [T]the sender is forced to retransmit all segments after the segment loss is detected by a retransmission timeout.

[...]

Figure 3 describes a TCP trace where in-order bytes up to the sequence number of 2028597920 are received correctly, at which point there is a segment loss. Unaware of the loss, the sender continues to send data up to 2028605220, at which point it retransmits the lost segment and the entire pipe of data up to 2028605220 again. This results in retransmission of five packets which were actually successfully received.

[image: Figure 3]

*Typical retransmission and draining of pipe.*

By using the Selective Acknowledgement scheme, a receiver can selectively acknowledge segments that were received after the loss. The sender then needs only to retransmit the lost segments. These lost segments or packets are also referred to as "holes" in the data stream.

---

If you are only looking at fast retransmit / fast recovery characteristics as per [RFC 2581](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2581.txt), then the retransmission behavior would be somewhat different. `HOST B` would issue duplicate ACKs as per your figure hinting towards `HOST A` that a segment needs retransmission. And of course it also would receive and buffer the subsequent segments up to the size of its receive window - this is how the segment reordering mechanism works. Upon reception of the missing segment, the reordering mechanism would be able to assemble the stream and `HOST B`'s stack would ACK the last received segment (157).